# Which mongoose model would be more efficient?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am new to `no-sql`. I am trying to build a simple e-commerce app in nodejs. Now for the product i need to build CRUD operations so that only owner can edit them, rest have `READ-ONLY` access. The main question is which would be a better implementation ?

The current code that i have is like

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('product',new mongoose.Schema({
  owner      : {type: String},
  title      : {type: String},
  ...
}));
```

The owner is actually the `_id` from my user model. Basically this is something like a foreign key. Is this the valid method to go around or should i add an array inside the `user model` to store the list of objects that he owns ?

Also i would like to have validation if what i just did for owner, storing `UID` in `String` is best practice or should i do something else to reference the user model.

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of document databases is you shouldn't have foreign relationships; All the data your document needs should be denormalized in the document.

So inside your `product` document, you should be duplicating all the owner details you need. You *can* store their `_id` as well for lookup, but don't use a string for this, use an actual `ObjectId()`.

For more about denormalization see [The Little MongoDB Book](http://openmymind.net/2011/3/28/The-Little-MongoDB-Book/)

> Yet another alternative to using joins is to denormalize your data. Historically, denormalization was reserved for performance-sensitive code, or when data should be snapshotted (like in an audit log). However, with the ever- growing popularity of NoSQL, many of which don’t have joins, denormalization as part of normal modeling is becoming increasingly common. This doesn’t mean you should duplicate every piece of information in every document. However, rather than letting fear of duplicate data drive your design decisions, consider modeling your data based on what information belongs to what document.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the link, Just so we are on the same page, rather i should create an array with Objectid object for users ?

Comment: Not OP, but I think they're suggesting that you put owner information inside the product model directly, and then also potentially adding an array of product ids to the relevant owner. However, you should note that taking this approach will require you to consider additional issues such as updating the owner may require you to update N products as well, for the denormalized owner data. Another concern is that when you assign an owner to a product, you must also update the owner's array of product ids.